# How to make a drawing tool that follows mouse cursor?

Tags: python, mouse, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a app with Python that follows the mouse cursor. My attempts don't actually get close at all.

```
import turtle

o=1
Gps = turtle.Turtle()


for i in range(4):
    while o==1:
```

I tried to make it to get mouse cursor position.

I have tried, but all I get is errors saying  ? is not defined

Comment: use `turtle.mainloop()` or `turtle.done()` at the end to keep window open.

Comment: i did'nt because this import turtle

o=1
loopy = turtle.Turtle()


for i in range(4):
    while o==1:
    
        loopy.forward(50)
        loopy.right(90)
        loopy.backward(10)
        loopy.left(30)
        loopy.circle(10)
        loopy.right(70)
        loopy.left(30)
        loopy.forward(40)
        loopy.circle(30)
        loopy.backward(20)
        loopy.backward(80)
        loopy.right(17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw line only when you click mouse on screen

```
import turtle

def move_turtle(x, y):
    turtle.setpos(x, y)

turtle.onscreenclick(move_turtle)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Draw when you drag turtle (you have to catch turtle, keep pressed mouse button and move mouse with turtle)

```
import turtle

def move_turtle(x, y):
    turtle.setpos(x, y)

turtle.ondrag(move_turtle)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Maybe if you will have turtles with different colors or sizes then you can draw different lines.

---

To follow mouse when you don't press button would need to use Tkinter's functions hidden in turtle.

I think you should use other module to create drawing tool - tkinter, PyQt, PySize, wxPython, other GUI.

Comment: And how do you change color of the turtle ? just asking

Comment: don't have to answer

Comment: read documentation: [Turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html)

Comment: @Knight Use `turtle.color()`.